# Python pandas create new column with groupby with custom agg function

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame:

```
from random import random, randint
from pandas import DataFrame

t = DataFrame({"metasearch":["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"],
                   "market":["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"],
                   "bid":[random() for i in range(8)],
                   "clicks": [randint(0,10) for i in range(8)],
                   "country_code":["A","A","A","A","A","B","A","B"]})
```

I want to fit LinearRegression for each `market`, so I:

1) Group df - `groups = t.groupby(by="market")`

2) Prepare function to fit model on a group -

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
def group_fitter(group):
    lr = LinearRegression()
    X = group["bid"].fillna(0).values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = group["clicks"].fillna(0)
    lr.fit(X, y)
    return lr.coef_[0] # THIS IS A SCALAR
```

3) Create a new Series with `market` as an index and `coef` as a value:

```
s = groups.transform(group_fitter)
```

**But the 3rd step fails:** KeyError: ('bid_cpc', 'occurred at index bid')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need instead `transform` use `apply` because working with more columns in function together and for new column use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
def group_fitter(group):
    lr = LinearRegression()
    X = group["bid"].fillna(0).values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = group["clicks"].fillna(0)
    lr.fit(X, y)
    return lr.coef_[0] # THIS IS A SCALAR

groups = t.groupby(by="market")
df = t.join(groups.apply(group_fitter).rename('new'), on='market')
print (df) 
        bid  clicks country_code market metasearch       new
0  0.462734       9            A      A          A -8.632301
1  0.438869       5            A      B          B  6.690289
2  0.047160       9            A      A          A -8.632301
3  0.644263       0            A      B          B  6.690289
4  0.579040       0            A      A          A -8.632301
5  0.820389       6            B      B          B  6.690289
6  0.112341       5            A      A          A -8.632301
7  0.432502       0            B      B          B  6.690289
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return the group from the function instead of the coefficient.

```
# return the group instead of scaler value
def group_fitter(group):
    lr = LinearRegression()
    X = group["bid"].fillna(0).values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = group["clicks"].fillna(0)
    lr.fit(X, y)
    group['coefficient'] = lr.coef_[0] # <- This is the changed line
    return group

# the new column gets added to the data 
s = groups.apply(group_fitter)
```